# Swift prepare for segue and dismiss controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to dismiss a tableview controller with a navigation controller embeded after performing a segue.

Here's my code:

```
class SelectAlbum: UITableViewController {
..............
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let destination = (segue.destination as? CustomNavigationBar)?.topViewController as? AddPhotoPostVC
        else { fatalError("unexpected view controller for segue") }
    guard let cell = sender as? AlbumListCells else { fatalError("unexpected cell for segue") }

    switch SegueIdentifier(rawValue: segue.identifier!)! {
    case .showAllPhotos:
        destination.fetchResult = allPhotos
        destination.headerTitleBtnString = cell.allPhotoTitle.text!
    case .showCollection:

        // get the asset collection for the selected row
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)!
        let collection: PHCollection
        switch Section(rawValue: indexPath.section)! {
        case .smartAlbums:
            collection = smartAlbums.object(at: indexPath.row)
        case .userCollections:
            collection = userCollections.object(at: indexPath.row)
        default: return // not reached; all photos section already handled by other segue
        }

        // configure the view controller with the asset collection
        guard let assetCollection = collection as? PHAssetCollection
            else { fatalError("expected asset collection") }
        destination.fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection, options: nil)
        destination.assetCollection = assetCollection
        destination.headerTitleBtnString = cell.collectionTitle.text!
    }
}
........
}
```

The issue is that if I dismiss the controller in the prepare for segue function than the segue is not performed and I get and error in my console log: "Attempt to present....whose view is not in the window hierarchy!".

How can I dismiss the controller and pass the data?
Thank you.

Comment: set some value and on viewDidAppear check that value to determine if you should change something

Comment: @Lu_ in viewDidAppear i have the function that create the collection view with the data passed after the segue. However if i dismiss the collectionview will not be updated... it's like the segue is not performed but just the controller dimissed

Comment: if you want to dismiss it why do you try to update it? you cant update elements in one controller from completely separate controller.

Comment: @Lu_ i want to dismiss the tableviewcontroller after the segue is performed and the data are passed to the other controller. the segue will pass the data and the receiver update the cells whit the data received

Comment: so update on view did appear not on prepare for segue

Comment: i do update on viewdidappear... the problem is dismissing the controller where the prepare for segue is...

Comment: so don't do that on prepare, you should not do that in prepare

Comment: @Lu_ exactly my problem... don't know where i should do it..

Comment: Looks like you're trying to show new controller from controller which has been dismissed. Probably you should make some callback from tableCiewController to it's parent. And this parent should show new controller for example with performSegue: and prepare it.

Comment: @Che the code i working... when i click on the tableview cell the other controller (AddPhoto) is presented and the collection view is update. My issues is that i cannot dismiss the controller where i perform the segue. It remains in the stack and if i dismiss the addPhoto VC after the segue it returns to the SelectAlbumVC (controller where i perform the segue) instead of going to the home page...

Comment: It's little bit tricky… But… You can play with self.navigationController?.viewControllers property and modify stack of controllers… In AddPhoto's viewDidLoad() method just remove SelectAlbumVC from the stack.
But it's not good solution as for me )

Comment: @Che thought about it... and didn't convinced me either... not sure how to do it.. but i cannot leave it in stack or it will not works as its suppose to..

Comment: @Marco Also you can override back button (set leftBarButtonItem in the AddPhoto controller) and call there popToRootViewController:. Or setup navigation's delegate and decide from delegate's methods should you move to rootViewController or not )

Comment: @Che if i do like this the SelectAlbumVC will always be in stack right?